# How to Raise MR for two different Branch from one branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I am on task/common branch. I take pull from the release branch and push the code and raise MR for the release Branch. now i need to push the same changes to the develop branch as well from task/common branch. can i directly took the pull from develop branch and raise MR?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can take a pull from base branch (develop in this case) and then raise another pull request.

There is no shortcut to do this. So you will have to follow the steps twice once for `develop` and once for `release` branch